# Starting a WCF service in Windows Service when initialization takes a long time

Tags: windows, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF project that I host in a windows Service (actually I use topshelf) and it runs fine.  I have to make changes however that will cause the initialization to take substantially longer.  This causes problems when the service starts as it times out while executing the WCF Service constructor.
I wanted to reduce the amount of code in the constructor and then when the service was opened I would do my longer running initializations.  I put register the open event in the WCF ctor but it does not seem to be called.

```
    public WCFService()
    {
        this.Faulted += WCF_Faulted;
        this.Opened += WCF_Opened;
        ...
```

and event handlers

```
void WCF_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    void WCF_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I am guessing that I am not implementing this correctly.

I was able to trap the opened event in the servicehost but then I dont know how to access the instance (it is a singleton) to call a method on it.

Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you start a `Task` or `Thread` to initialize your WCF service? That way, the OnStart method won't take long at all.

Comment: I thought of that.  But what I really wanted to accomplish was a way to defer the init routine until after the service started  and was looking for an event in which to hook into.